# Which sorting algorithm causes minimum disturbance in a given array?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, selection-sort

I had got this question on an online portal,

> There are 100 people, seated in a row of 100 chairs.
> You want to sort these people by their first names. However, the
> individuals are lazy and do not wish to move from their seats.
> Luckily, you know that of the 100 people, only a few are out of order.
> In order to disturb the fewest number of people, which algorithm
> would NOT be ideal?
>
> Options
>
> 1. bubble sort
> 2. heap sort
> 3. selection sort
> 4. merge sort
> 5. All of the above are going to upset approximately the
>    same number of people

It seems that **Selection Sort should be ideal** while others move a lot of people. (I even confirmed it via code).
But that is not a valid option.

So am I wrong, or is the question?

Comment: The question is asking which one would NOT be ideal, not which one would be ideal.

Comment: heap sort seems likely to be the most disruptive

Comment: (With *people*, a lot of concurrency is possible: At time t₂ₙ, persons in position p₂ₙ conditionally swap with p₂ₙ₊₁, at t₂ₙ₊₁ p₂ₙ₊₁ with p₂₍ₙ₊₁₎ (refer [odd-even sort](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Odd%E2%80%93even_sort)). (with my current font, the ₙ is not "as sub-scripted" as the others.))

Comment: Is the plan to actually run the sorting algorithm by moving them from chair to chair or is the plan to first figure out their position and then move them to the right spot? In the first case how many variations of merge sort are there? In the latter case it seems like a question of stable sort

Comment: "The question is asking which one would NOT be ideal, not which one would be ideal". True, but since selection sort IS ideal, I cannot choose option 5. But bubble and heap sort can move every single person from their seat; so even that answer will not be correct. Which option would you choose?